# Docker image gcr.io/google_containers/kube2sky:1.15 source code location

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Somebody knows what source code and version were used to create docker image gcr.io/google_containers/kube2sky:**1.15**?

The latest version where I could find kube2sky in kubernetes repository is the branch release-1.2 in folder: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.2/cluster/addons/dns/kube2sky

But looking at the kube2sky.go that is inside the docker container (doing docker exec) is not the same as the kube2sky.go of the github repository.

Please if somebody can help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

kube2sky is pretty old. It used to be stored in the kubernetes main repo, but was removed quite a while back.

You can find it here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/1c8140c2ac1fb7cb6ddbadc5e1efb3c0beefb8df/cluster/addons/dns/kube2sky

Version tag: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/1c8140c2ac1fb7cb6ddbadc5e1efb3c0beefb8df/cluster/addons/dns/kube2sky/Makefile#L24

the last known version of kube2sky before it was replaced with kubedns seems to be here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/5762ebfc6318eabbe870b02239226ab74e2e699b/cluster/addons/dns/kube2sky/kube2sky.go

It was removed in this PR
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/26335/files

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But I compared the kube2sky.go that is inside the container of image gcr.io/google_containers/kube2sky:1.15 and is not the same as the one you specified, it has many code differences :(

Comment: I updated the answer and added the last known version. if there are still differences, go back through the commit history till you find the right version

Comment: I compared and they have 3 small differences, but I think it's ok, they seems to be fixes.
They are:
* line 195: "err := ks.generateSRVRecord(subdomain, portSegment, recordLabel, recordKey, int(endpointPort.Port))" container doesnt convert port.Port to int.
* line 211: "if hostRecord, exists := podHostnames[address.IP]; exists && len(validation.IsDNS1123Label(hostRecord.HostName)) == 0 {" container doesnt check validation len.
* line 346: "err = ks.generateSRVRecord(subdomain, portSegment, recordLabel, subdomain, int(port.Port))"  container doesnt convert port.Port to int.
Thank you again